# jq include results of a filter inside a new filter

Tags: json, jq

I want to use the results of a `jq` filter inside another `jq` filter. I've done it with `xargs` but I feel It has to be a better way with a simple `jq` run.

## Example:

```
]$ cat test.json 
{
   "prof" : {
      "Sma00K279a" : {
         "SMLT_RS00075" : {
            "Sma00K279a" : {
               "SMLT_RS00075" : 1.0
            }
         },
         "SMLT_RS00180#" : {
            "Sma00K279a" : {
               "SMLT_RS00180#" : 1.0
            }
         },
         "Smlt0558" : {
            "Sma00K279a" : {
               "Smlt3938" : 1.0
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "redundant_removed" : {
      "Sma00K279a" : {
         "SMLT_RS22460" : "SMLT_RS22690",
         "Smlt0558" : "Smlt3938",
         "Smlt3573" : "Smlt1093"
      }
   }
}
```

## My solution:

```
]$ jq '.redundant_removed.Sma00K279a|keys[]' test.json |tr -d \"|xargs -tI% jq '.prof.Sma00K279a.%' test.json 
jq .prof.Sma00K279a.SMLT_RS22460 test.json 
null
jq .prof.Sma00K279a.Smlt0558 test.json 
{
  "Sma00K279a": {
    "Smlt3938": 1
  }
}
jq .prof.Sma00K279a.Smlt3573 test.json 
null
```

## My question:

Is there a better way to do this with a single `jq` run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is.

```
$ jq '.prof.Sma00K279a[.redundant_removed.Sma00K279a|keys[]]' file
null
{
  "Sma00K279a": {
    "Smlt3938": 1
  }
}
null
```

Or a bit more generic one:

```
$ jq '(.prof|keys[]) as $k | .prof[$k][.redundant_removed[$k]|keys[]]' file
null
{
  "Sma00K279a": {
    "Smlt3938": 1
  }
}
null
```